# How to iterate on an Ansible dictionary of lists

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible

In an Ansible task, I want to iterate on all subelements of each dictionary category. The container I am using looks like this:

```yaml
myDict:
  - {category1: el00, category2: [el10, el11], category3: [el20, el21, el22, el23]}
```

The expected output would be :

```yaml
msg: el00
msg: el10 el11
msg: el20 el21 el22 el23
```

Comment: Your `myDict` is not a dictionary but rather a list containing a dictionary. Was that really your intention?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take into account the fact that the variable *myDict* is a list and that there might be more items create a file

```yaml
shell> cat iteration.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ i.0 }} {{ i.1 }} {{ i.2 }}"
  with_nested:
    - "{{ item.category1 }}"
    - "{{ item.category2 }}"
    - "{{ item.category3 }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: i
```

and include it in the loop

```yaml
    - include_tasks: iteration.yml
      loop: "{{ myDict }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: el00 el10 el20
  msg: el00 el10 el21
  msg: el00 el10 el22
  msg: el00 el10 el23
  msg: el00 el11 el20
  msg: el00 el11 el21
  msg: el00 el11 el22
  msg: el00 el11 el23
```

---

If you want to iterate the first item in the list only the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0 }} {{ item.1 }} {{ item.2 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ myDict.0.category1 }}"
        - "{{ myDict.0.category2 }}"
        - "{{ myDict.0.category3 }}"
```